# Explicit "return" key word in Rust function

Tags: rust

I have just started learning Rust, and I have seen in the documentation that to return a value from a function, the expression is just placed by itself at the end of the function without a semicolon like this:

```rust
fn times_2(x: i32) -> i32 {
    x * 2
}
```

I know an alternative way is to explicitly write `return` at the start of the line, but although this isn't done in any of the examples in the docs, it seems clearer and more readable to me.

Is it a bad practice to explicitly write `return` when it's not needed, or does it not matter?

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/rust/comments/2v82ag/why_isnt_the_syntax_of_return_statements_explicit/

Comment: I wouldn't say it is a bad practice but it is not idiomatic. In some cases you might need to state `return` explicitly but personally i am trying to avoid that, IMO that makes my implementations clearer and well divided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While it is certainly possible to write `return x * 2;` in this case and it's functionally equivalent, it isn't idiomatic in Rust.  Different languages have different best practices for this: in Perl, many people prefer to be explicit and write `return`, whereas in Ruby and Rust it's generally preferred to omit it.

Note that other contexts use this last value as the value of the block as well: closures, if-else blocks, match blocks, and various others.  `return` isn't valid or isn't equivalent in most of those contexts, so you'll need to get used to seeing this syntax in other places.

Probably the best argument for omitting it is that `cargo clippy` warns about it, and that's a commonly used tool for linting your code.  Even if *you* don't love that tool, other people working on Rust code will have it enabled in their editor by default, and they'll see all the style warnings if you omit it.  It *is* a best practice to keep your code free of clippy warnings unless you have a compelling reason not to (like backwards compatibility with older Rust versions).